# Как быть, если нужно где-то хранить изменения нетреканных файлов?

Tags: менеджмент, git, phpstorm

К примеру, пишется какой-либо плагин на jQuery, разумно, если в production-ready ветку попадает уже минифицированный код. Но, чтобы было проще ориентироваться в куче коммитов и веток (в phpstorm), код в них нужно как-то оставлять оригинальным (т.е. не минифицированным)... или любая другая подобная ситуация, например, настройки htaccess (вроде и не нужны в production-ready, но и untracked их оставлять дорого). Для этой цели в develop ветку (бог с ним) вливаем эти файлы вместе с минифицированным кодом... а как потом из develop ветки влить в production-ready, чтобы смержился только минифицированный код? Т.е. чтобы оригинальный код в production-ready не попал?

PS Пример с jQuery плагином приведен исключительно для аналогии, чтобы обозначить границы вопроса.

Comment: сделайте локальную ветку, необязательно отправлять ее на сервер. Опять-же можно билд делать и не из самого git.

Comment: Но тогда другой разработчик ее не увидит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO конечно, но зачем минифицированный (читаем сгенерированный системой) код хранить в истории версий? Пусть он генерируется сам по себе относительно тех девелоперских версий, ветка которых на данный момент активна. Т.е. это дело автоматического скрипта/программы обфускатора, а не системы контроля версий.

Подобная проблема была при работе с LESS и выкладке минифицированного сгенерированного CSS. Решилось все именно так, на сервере (и локально у девелоперов) стоял скрипт который генерил минифицированную версию текущей ветки, а в GIT уходили только LESS файлы.

Comment: Интересное мнение, но тут другое - префекционизм. Ну для примера первая точка во времени/состоянии кода - это когда вы делаете git clone, вторая - когда вы впервые используете его. Между этими двумя состояниями сколько в коде нужно изменить? А не лучше ли будет, если сократить по максимуму телодвижения и танцы с бубном в коде на этом промежутке? В таком случае production-ready ветку можно вполне себе для непросвещенных пользователей на гитхаб выложить в свободном доступе... вот я к чему.

Comment: @АндрейТаланин: что касается гитхаба — он индексируется довольно быстро разными роботами, был случай когда человек на пару минут спалил пароли от сервера на Amazon, а потом быстро убрал через `push -f`. Так вот, за ночь там нафармили биткойнов на пару тысяч долларов чека за обслуживание ))

Comment: @АндрейТаланин: так что и ваш обфусцированный код наверняка найдут как деобфусцировать. Я же верно понимаю, что минификация — это что-то вроде обфускации для JS/CSS?